# DatabaseGeneratedOption.None as foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two models that are defined something like this:

```
public class ModelA
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ModelAId {get; set;}
}

public class ModelB
{
    [Key]
    public int ModelBId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("ModelA")]
    public int ModelAId {get; set;}
}
```

I apply `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)` to `ModelA` because I need to be able to manually set that key. The problem is that when I try to insert records for `ModelB`, Entity Framework throws up a primary key constraint error when I call `SaveChanges()`. I wonder if this is because the underlying SQL is legal, and the problem is that, due to the `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)` annotation, EntityFramework does not recognize `ModelAId` as an identity column and so cannot verify the foreign key constraint. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Can you include a simple repro of your issue?